# How to get multiple values from a switch

Tags: arrays, swift, switch-statement

I'm getting array of Int, which is film genres, and I need to give to each element corresponding genre (for example: 28 - "Action", 12 - "Adventure") and display them in tableView cell.

I could only display one genre, not multiple. Could you please help me fix a code and give some recommendations about how to properly get a genre.

```
func getGenre(filmGenres: [Int]) -> String {
    
    var genre: String = "Action"
    
    for i in filmGenres {
        
        switch i {
        case 28:
            genre = "Action"
        case 12:
            genre = "Adventure"
        case 16:
            genre = "Animation"
        case 35:
            genre = "Comedy"
        case 80:
            genre = "Crime"
        case 99:
            genre = "Documentary"
        case 18:
            genre = "Drama"
        case 10751:
            genre = "Family"
        case 14:
            genre = "Fantasy"
        case 36:
            genre = "History"
        case 27:
            genre = "Horror"
        case 10402:
            genre = "Music"
        case 9648:
            genre = "Mystery"
        case 10749:
            genre = "Romance"
        case 878:
            genre = "Science Fiction"
        case 10770:
            genre = "TV Movie"
        case 53:
            genre = "Thriller"
        case 10752:
            genre = "War"
        case 37:
            genre = "Western"
        default:
            return ""
    }
    }
       return genre
}
cell.filmGenre.text = movie.getGenre(filmGenres: movie.genreIDs!)
```

Comment: i guess you should have  one parameter not an array here as a parameter as you return 1 value not array

Comment: Rather than using an Int, it would be better to define a custom enum for your film genres. You might want to use `filmGenres.map(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to get a string that contains all the genres from the genreIDs array.

```
let genreIds = [28, 12, 99, 12]

// Just to make sure we have unique genres. 
// You may skip this if your application logic ensures this
let uniqGenreIds = Array(Set(genreIds))  

// Create an sorted array with the textual genre names:
let stringGenres = uniqGenreIds.map {
    (intGenre) -> String in
    switch intGenre {
        case 28:
            return "Action"
        case 12:
            return "Adventure"
        case 16:
            return "Animation"
        default: return "unknown"
    }
}.sorted()

// Join the strings:
let allGenres = stringGenres.joined(separator: ",")
print (allGenres) // Action,Adventure,unknown
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Brilliant implementation. Now I understand how to get multiple values from switch. So we must not just use map but also call sort func. Is let uniqGenreIds = Array(Set(genreIds)) checks if array doesn't contain identical values?

Comment: Yes, the statements create a `Set` (which will throw away duplicates) and then from that distinct values a new array.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good case to embrace enums, you'll have an enum of Genre

```
enum Genre: Int {
  case Action = 28
  case Adventure = 12
  case Animation = 16
  //.. list all your cases

  var name: String {
     "\(self)"
  }
}
```

Then in your logic you can have something that look like

```
let genres = genreIds.compactMap(Genre.init).map(\.name).joined(separator: ",")
```

clean and easy to reason about :)